# How to change both opening and closing html tags in atom editor at the same time?

Tags: atom-editor

If I have something like this `<span>some<span>text</span></span>` and I want to change outermost span tag to something else, and to change both the opening and the closing tag at the same time, how can I do that with the Atom editor? I know that cmd+d shortcut selects the same text forward but in this case it will select the inner span tags also which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In early Alpha there is a new package (less than 24 days old at time of edit) which seems to have the requested functionality [Double Tag](https://github.com/dsandstrom/atom-double-tag)

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: By now there is a build in way in atom: Cmd + D, D. (press D twice)
This will select the next occurrence and then you'll be able to edit both at the same time. Note: this only works when you are at the starting tag with the cursor.

Answer (score 13):

With `ctrl + (click in text)` (or `cmd + (click in text)` on Mac) you can create multiple cursors. So you can add a second one to change both tags at once.

Thats the only method I know atm.

Edit:
There is a shortcut `ctrl + d` or `cmd + d` which with you can mark same occurrences of the text.

There is also a package which does exactly what you want: https://github.com/dsandstrom/atom-double-tag

Answer (score 8):

you can select both tags using:

Highlight the name of the opening tag
Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to highlight the name of the closing tag
Type in the replacement tag name

reagrds :)

Comment: Yes. And, there's no need to highlight: place the cursor at the beginning, into, or at the end of a word (any word, not just a tag name) and press Cmd+D to select the word. Continue pressing Cmd+D for selecting next instance(s) of the word. Then type to replace all of the selections with a new text.

Comment: Editing opening and closing tags together with Cmd+D do not work when there is another (opening) tag with the same name between. (e.g. an outer DIV with another DIV inside does not work).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> deselects the current selection when followed by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

So, your keyboard riff goes like this: hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and press <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like this is currently possible in Atom. Please refer to the following for more details:

- [Discussion on the Atom forum about exactly this issue](https://discuss.atom.io/t/edit-replace-current-html-tag/11432/2)
- [Issue on the bracket-matcher package with a request to add this functionality - currently still open](https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher/issues/63)

If you're interested, you could take a stab at adding this functionality to the bracket-matcher package...

note: in early Alpha there is a new package (less than 24 days old at time of edit) which seems to have the requested functionality [Double Tag](https://github.com/dsandstrom/atom-double-tag)

Comment: this answer is out of date.  The double-tag is working and well supported. But also see my answer below, [emmet package has been released](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/releases/tag/v0.1.0) long before you're answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Double Tag package](https://atom.io/packages/double-tag) works great but you can also use the popular [Emmet package](https://atom.io/packages/emmet) which has a lot of other cool features for heavy html / web dev use cases.